# Laravel 4 Unexpected NULL value with redirect::action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have problem with laravel4. it is as following.

there is a controller function that ends with:

```
   return Redirect::action('JobController@postAddJob_02', array('param1'=>'teststring'));
```

the function that should receive the parameter is as follows:

```
public function postAddJob_02(){

        $test = Input::get('param1');

        dd($test);    
    }
```

$test always remains NULL instead of 'teststring'
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How does the route look like?

Comment: there is no route here , i just want it to go from function to function. i thought the Redirect::action function was made for that?

Comment: `Redirect::action` will make an HTTP redirect. If you want to call another function just invoke it like `$this->postAddJob_02('teststring')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the parameter in the argument list of the action. Laravel sees that the argument list is empty and thus returns `null`.

```
public function postAddJob_02($param1) {
   dd($param1);    
}
```

Comment: i changed it to    
    public function postAddJob_02($param1){
     
        dd($param1);
      
        
    }   but now i get the following error: Missing argument 1 for JobController::postAddJob_02()

Comment: @Vudew I think parameters only work if you have your route look like this (with brackets): `param1={param1}`

Comment: i changed it to what you said. the result was the error : Missing argument 1 for JobController::postAddJob_02()

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you should access route parameters like this:

```
Route::input('param1')
```

Comment: Nope, still getting NULL sadly.